# Как создать TCP server/client на основе IPv6?

Tags: boost, qt, c++, nat

Несколько дней идет попытка связать два компьютера в Интернете. Оба находятся за `NAT`. Я все пытался как-то воспользоваться `STUN`, скачал с `github` готовый сервер и клиент, но так и не понял как их применить - то ли свой программный код внедрить в эти программы или как-то нужно воспользоваться ими консольно.

Теперь рассматриваю способ посредством `IPv6`. Насколько я понял - это самый простой способ обхода `NAT` (да по современее наверное). Мой провайдер поддерживает `v6` и сетевой интерфейс получает кучу "непонятных" мне адресов. Но, почитав немного, выяснил что из всего этого меня вроде должны интересовать номера начинающиеся с `2000:-3fff`, т.к. именно они представляют хост в сети Интернет.

Подскажите как создать `TCP-сервер` на основе `IPv6` и как подсоединиться к такому серверу. Подойдет любая подсказка с использование `Qt` или `boost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут есть хороший пример - [IPv6-simple-tcp-client-server](http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2012/12/simple-tcp-client-server-sockets.html)